# Delete files older than specific month

Tags: php, date

I create that script:

```
$zips = glob("*.zip");

usort($zips, function($a, $b) { return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b); });

$dateFile = date("F d Y H:i:s", filectime($zips[0]));
$dateNow = date("F d Y H:i:s");

echo "dateFile = " . $dateFile;
echo "<br />";
echo "dateNow = " . $dateNow
```

Output is:

```
dateFile = August 03 2017 10:23:47
dateNow = August 03 2017 10:43:27
```

I want to check if file is older that month a.k.a dateNow - dateFile ? in months?

Comment: What do you mean with `mounts`? Months, minutes or what, I'm confused

Comment: Ohh sorry, months, edit!

Comment: Look at [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php), you can format the date interval in months or whatever you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it like the following

```
if(strtotime(dateFile) < strtotime('first day of last month', time())) {
   //file is older than 1 month
}
```

You can also use the function for 30 days from now. This will check if the file is older than 30 days backwards from the time you will do this condition.

```
if(strtotime(dateFile) < (time()-2592000)) {
   //file is older than 1 month
}
```

`2592000` are 30 days in seconds.

Comment: Please keep in mind, that is the first day of the last month. So it can be more than 30 days. I have added a another function, which check if the file is older than 30 days from the time now on.

Comment: echo $dateFile; // August 03 2017 10:54:00
echo "<br />";

if(strtotime($dateFile) < (time()+7200)) {
   echo "it's older";
}

Here output is "it;s older, but u can see file is create on 03.2017 in 10:54:00 so it's not over 2 hours ..

Comment: my fault: change the + with an -. Changed it also in the post.

Answer (score 0):

get diff from current date and file date ; and check if older than 30 days delete it:

```
$date1 = date_create(date("Y-m-d")); // current date
$date2 = date_create($file_date); // change file date to Y-m-d format
$diff  = date_diff($date1,$date2);
if($diff->format("%R") == '+' && $diff->format("%a") != 0){
    if($diff->format("%a") > 30)
        //delete file
}else
    //delete file
```

Comment: You can also use `$diff->format('%m')` to get the months

Comment: @xander that's true ✔

Comment: I think this option is to oversized for the question. You can do it in shorter way, like mine.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete all files older than a month and you are on a linux machine, you can use a bash command to fulfil your request. On windows you need another command, but it works too.

this command finds all files older than 30 days in `/path/to/files` this folder and deletes them. **Make sure that your path is correct or wrong files get deleted!**

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

---

I forgot to post the correct PHP code!

```
exec("find /path/to/files* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;");
```